# How should I select features for logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, feature-selection

I tried several ways of selecting predictors for a logistic regression in R. I used lasso logistic regression to get rid of irrelevant features, cutting their number from 60 to 24, then I used those 24 variables in my stepAIC logistic regression, after which I further cut 1 variable with p-value of approximately 0.1. What other feature selection methods I can or even should use? I tried to look for Anova correlation coefficient analysis, but I didn't find any examples for R. And I think I cannot use correlation heatmap in this situation since my output is categorical? I seen some instances recommending Lasso and StepAIC, and other instances criticising them, but I didn't find any definitive comprehensive alternative, which left me confused.

Answer (score 1):

Given the methodological nature of your question you might also get a more detailed answer at Cross Validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

From your information provided, 23-24 independent variables seems quite a number to me. If you do not have a large sample, remember that overfitting might be an issue (i.e. low cases to variables ratio). Indications of overfitting are large parameter estimates & standard errors, or failure of convergence, for instance. You obviously have already used stepwise variable selection according to `stepAIC` which would have also been my first try if I would have chosen to let the model do the variable selection.

If you spot any issues with standard errors/parameter estimates further options down the road might be to collapse categories of independent variables, or check whether there is any evidence of multicollinearity which could also result in deleting highly-correlated variables and narrow down the number of remaining features.

Apart from a strictly mathematical approach you might also want to identify features that are likely to be related to your outcome of interest according to your underlying content hypothesis and your previous experience, meaning to look at the model from your point of view as expert in your field of interest.

If sample size is not an issue and the point is reduction of feature numbers, you may consider running a principal component analysis (PCA) to find out about highly correlated features and do the regression with the PCAs instead which are non-correlated linear combination of your "old" features. A package to accomplish PCA is `factoextra` using `prcomp` or `princomp` arguments http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/118-principal-component-analysis-in-r-prcomp-vs-princomp/

Comment: My sample is 300,000+ observations, so the number of variables isn't really the issue. The issue is their weak prediction power. The binary classification I am doing has class imbalance of about 1:7, although it is not sever, it shows. I know I have to do cost-sensitive modelling instead, however I still need to show the low performance of standard approach ML models. But a model like this logreg is giving only 60% sensitivity and 50% specifictiy after thresholding and about 65% accuracy, so I wanted to at least increase it's performance by conducting a proper feature selection procedure.

Comment: See my edited answer.